# Mohr circle curvatures in constant negative Gauss curvature K Chebyshev net

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

In order to verify vanishing normal curvature $\kappa_n$ *everywhere* for asymptotic lines as hyperbolic geodesic representation of a Chebyshev net I have used relations represented in the Mohr circle:

$$ \left(\kappa_n - \frac{\kappa_1+\kappa_2}{2}\right)^2 +\tau_g^2 =  \left(\frac{\kappa_1+\kappa_2}{2}\right)^2 \tag 1$$
which simplifies to
$$\kappa_n^2 -\kappa_n({\kappa_1+\kappa_2} ) + \tau_g^2 +K=0\label{2} \tag{2} $$

By virtue of the Beltrami-Enneper theorem constant geodesic torsion is given by  $\tau_g$ and $K$  constants related as:

$$ \tau_g^2 +K=0\label{3}\tag{3}$$

The concurrent point $A$ has $\kappa_n =0$ common for all constant $K<0$ circles as expected and drawn below.

However substituting  into \eqref{3} into \eqref{2}, with standard mean curvature symbol $ 2H = (\kappa_1+\kappa_2)$ we obtain *two normal curvatures*

$$ \kappa_n =0,~ \kappa_n =2 H ;~ \text {  represented by O and O'} \label{4}\tag{4}$$

[image]

Two Mohr circles are drawn for vanishing normal curvatures by the Euler relation:

$$  \kappa_1 \cos ^2 \psi + \kappa_2 \sin ^2\psi =0 , ~ \kappa_{1,2}= \left(-\frac12,2\right);~ \tag{5}$$

The datum could be drawn either either at $O$ or $O'$ in either axis direction which is just a matter of choice.

I am unable to interpret a the geometric meaning of the second *positive*  normal curvature appearing at \eqref{4} that I believe does exist, nor can discard it as extraneous, spurious solution etc. In either case we have the same $\tau_g$ and $K$ clearly as shown.

The Mohr circle  representation finds components  correctly for a lot of mechanical tensors e.g. (stress, strain, curvature, moment of inertia etc.)

Thanks for comments and clarification towards possible  legitimizing of the non-zero normal curvature at $A'$.

EDIT 1:

From $ \eqref{3},\eqref{4}$ the normal curvature represented by $A'$ in the plot the relevant direction is

$$ -\kappa_n=  \kappa_1 \cos ^2 \psi + \kappa_2 \sin ^2\psi-(\kappa_1+\kappa_2) \tag 6 $$
or
$$ \kappa_n=  \kappa_1 \sin ^2 \psi + \kappa_2 \cos ^2\psi \tag 7 $$

This is not the Euler normal curvature, the scalar may be tentatively called normal curvature of $\pi/2$ tangent rotation.

It is recognized as ***orthogonal to the main hyperbolic geodesic asymptotic lines***. They are obtained by replacing the angle they make to surface meridian by its complement. $ \psi \to \pi/2- \psi $.

They are a pair of lines from the same tangent bundle with same $ \tau_g $ on same negative $K$ surface but are *not* asymptotes of vanishing $\kappa_n$.

[image]

They appear to rank along with hyperbolic geodesics
I did not find it mentioned any text books of differential geometry (including LP Eisenhart, HW Guggenheimer) that I had access to before now. If already mentioned in any literature kindly bring to my notice.

I shall upload the regular hyperbolics on the same pseudosphere with these new orthogonal trajectories in the  same image.. asap.

I thank you for upvotes and edits that encouraged this research.